# Вопрос о подключении Vue JS к лендингу

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

Сверстал лендинг с помощью GULP & SCSS. И теперь нужно подключить vue js, чтобы написать небольшую логику. Так как работаю впервые с vue появился вопрос, как правильно подключить vue js чтобы можно было использовать весь функционал (компоненты и тд). Я подключил через cdn, правильное ли это решение и будет ли все работать? Или лучше создать отдельный проект, вставить туда vue cli и уже туда вставлять готовую верстку?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Решение с cdn**

"+" - в случае если пользователь был на сайте который так же использует vue по этой ссылке, браузер не будет грузить его заново а возьмёт из кэша (в некоторых случаях приложение загрузиться быстрее)
"-" - Может возникнуть ситуация когда фаил по какойто причине не будет доступен (блокировка ip, ошибка сети, ошибка на DNS серверах) проще говоря больше стабильности